# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync doesn't take ClientSecrets in Google.APIs.Auth.OAuth2

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-authentication, google-oauth

According to this: [Google API Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.3/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Auth_1_1OAuth2_1_1GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker)

I should be able to pass a `ClientSecrets` as the first parameter, but using the latest version of Google.APIs.Auth.OAuth2 nugget (1.22.x) package it only accepts a `URI` to the client secrets.

I'm just trying to follow this: [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth) which instructed to use the `ClientSecrets` and I don't seem to be able to get the example code to run, likely because its out of date.

Comment: What platform is this targeting? .NET Desktop, .NET Core, or something else?

Comment: I believe this is linked to https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/940 This method appears to be set to private.   A pull request has already been made to fix it.